# jQuery ajax request to Flickr sporadically fails

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, flickr

Occasionally, an ajax request to Flickr's api will fail. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here - or if I'm just not handling things correctly - but the code works over 90% of the time. When it doesn't work, I get the following error message from Firefox's console:

```
TypeError: jQuery19109306644694293944_1362865216185 is not a function
```

(I am letting jquery generate the callback, which is why the callback is named like that.)

This is the code that sometimes fails:

```
function getAppropriateSize(photo){
    console.log("In getAppropriateSize");
    /** stuff. query is defined here **/
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&api_key='+flickrKey+'&photo_id='+query.id,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp:'jsoncallback',
        timeout:3000,
        success: function(sizes){
            console.log("In success - getAppropriateSize");
            /**determine the correct size**/
            flickrURL = sizes.sizes.size[currVal].source;
        },
        error: function(xmlhttprequest,textstatus,msg){
            console.log("In error - getAppropriateSize");
            /* handle error*/
         }
    });
}
```

I've checked what's returned when this happens and JSLint says it's valid javascript. flickrURL also gets set to a valid URL. I'm pretty mystified about what's causing this error - any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I was messing around and this time getAppropriateSize just received two separate messages from flickr for one call. The first one was

```
({stat:"fail", code:1, message:"Photo not found"})
```

The second one was the a full response from the server that also produced the TypeError mentioned above. However, the second response found the photo and gave me the sizes.